# How to get any property from .properties file without explicitly calling its getter

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

is there a way to get a property added in .properties file without calling its getter.

So what I am expecting is:

`application.properties`

```
name=user1
email=user@xyzdomain.com
contact=123-456-0789
header=val1,val2,val3
.
.
.
```

Now, how can I write a method like this:

```
public String getKey(String key) {
    // any key passed, eg: name and I should get its value
    // Do I have to create a switch statement to see which key it is and using the //mapping of its corresponding getter method, call that getter. Is there a better way?
    ...
}
```

So, any key passed, eg: name and I should get its value. Do I have to create a switch statement to see which key it is and using the mapping of its corresponding getter method, call that getter. Is there a better way?

Comment: did you try injecting `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`?

Answer (score 1):

`org.springframework.core.env.Environment` is an interface representing the environment (as well is your `application.properties`) in which the current application is running.

With its instance you can access any property value loaded for the application by the key.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
....

public String getKey(String key) {
    .....  
    return env.getProperty(key);
}
```